# How can I add row numbers to an ExtJS grid?

Tags: extjs, designer

In an ExtJS GridPanel, is there a way to design a column whose sole purpose is to act as a serial number column? This column will not need a `dataIndex` property. 
Right now, I am using a custom row numberer function, but this means the row numberer is defined in the grid.js file and all columns from grid.ui.js needs to be copied into grid.js. 
I am using the Ext designer.

EDIT: The crux of my question is: Is there a way to define a row numberer using the Ext designer?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

All you need is an `Ext.grid.RowNumberer` in your column definition.

```
var colModel = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel([
    new Ext.grid.RowNumberer(),
    {header: "Name", width: 80, sortable: true},
    {header: "Code", width: 50, sortable: true},
    {header: "Description", width: 200, sortable: true}
]);
```

Answer (score 7):

Not an answer, but just want to share this:-

On top of the `Ext.grid.RowNumberer`, you can have this small nifty hack which will increments your numbers correctly according to the page number that you are viewing if you have implemented `PagingToolbar` in your grid.

Below is my working example. I extended the original `Ext.grid.RowNumberer` to avoid confliction.

```
Kore.ux.grid.RowNumberer = Ext.extend(Ext.grid.RowNumberer, {
    renderer: function(v, p, record, rowIndex) {
        if (this.rowspan) {
            p.cellAttr = 'rowspan="'+this.rowspan+'"';
        }
        var st = record.store;
        if (st.lastOptions.params && st.lastOptions.params.start != undefined && st.lastOptions.params.limit != undefined) {
            var page = Math.floor(st.lastOptions.params.start/st.lastOptions.params.limit);
            var limit = st.lastOptions.params.limit;
            return limit*page + rowIndex+1;
        }else{
            return rowIndex+1;
        }
    }
});
```

---

And the code below is the original `renderer` from `Ext.grid.RowNumberer`, which, to me, pretty ugly because the numbers is fixed all the time no matter what page number it is.

```
renderer : function(v, p, record, rowIndex){
    if(this.rowspan){
        p.cellAttr = 'rowspan="'+this.rowspan+'"';
    }
    return rowIndex+1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For version 4.2 very very easy:

Just add a new column like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'rownumberer',
    width: 40,
    sortable: false,
    locked: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ExtJS 4.2.1 working code below:

```
// Row numberer correct increasing
Ext.override(Ext.grid.RowNumberer, {
    renderer: function(v, p, record, rowIndex) {
        if (this.rowspan) {
            p.cellAttr = 'rowspan="'+this.rowspan+'"';
        }
        var st = record.store;

        if (st.lastOptions.page != undefined && st.lastOptions.start != undefined && st.lastOptions.limit != undefined) {
            var page = st.lastOptions.page - 1;
            var limit = st.lastOptions.limit;
            return limit*page + rowIndex+1;
        } else {
            return rowIndex+1;
        }
    }
});
```